# Pandas - check every part of a field to extract data to save on a different field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset (CSV file), which I load into Pandas, to be parsed.

Among various fields, there is one which is a mashup string of various info that I would like to separate and have in their own field. I did try to use split on that field, but I get carried over also data that I don't care about.

Is there a way to parse a specific field for every line in the pandas dataset, and say something like `if the string contain X then put X in a new field under the name of "car brand"` for example.

This is an example of how my mashed up field look like

```
Compound X222-12 Mixed 23.3
Compound 13.2 Single AP 128-A
Element X221-X 55.1 Mixed
Compound 720TC-1 Single RS 69.5
Element F332-2 Double 2.7
```

Each item is divided by a space, and the final outcome I would like, is to get all this data and put in a proper field, so it will look like this:

```
itemtype itemcode extra_info frequency_value
Compound X222-12  Mixed      23.3
Compound 128-A    Single AP  13.2
Element  X221-X   Mixed      55.1
Compound 720TC-1  Single RS  69.5
Element  F332-2   Double     2.7
```

The issue I am having, is that not every field is in the same place at times, so the frequency may come before the itemcode or the extra info may have more than one string in it.

I tried this to split, but this didn't work out

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df['splitdata1'], df['splitdata2'], df['splitdata3'], df['splitdata4']  = df['content'].str.split(' ' )
print (df)
```

Am I using Pandas incorrectly? Should I manage the strings before parsing the CSV file?

Comment: In the case of `Compound 13.2 Single AP 128-A`, how can the code know if it is `Single=AP 128-A` vs `Single AP=128-A`?

Comment: For that, I know that the values are set; so it can only be Single AP or Single RS; I have a table with accepted values that I can compare the string to

Comment: Is there any simple rule we can use, such as "values never contain spaces so it must be `Single AP=128-A`?  Or are we really stuck with a lookup table?

Comment: Sadly I have a list of `allowed values`; which is why I did not go for the route of extract the strings in pure python and do comparison. I was hoping that pandas somehow is able to get logic on string comparison, so I can separate the values

Comment: Maybe `Series.str.startswith()` is your only option.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot with an implementation